# No check box object in the Interface Builder Library

Tags: interface-builder

So I cannot find a checkbox in my Object Library. I only have a folder called Objects. How do I add the folder to the Object Library where the checkboxes are?

Comment: Eh... I have no idea what you are asking... Please give an explanation that people can understand. Then we can help you

Comment: I assume you are talking about the Interface Builder in Xcode?

Comment: In my storyboard when I want to add a checkbox button it doesn't appear is what I mean

Comment: But I know there is a library called Object Library who has all these buttons... but I don't know how to add that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS does not supply a standard checkbox control. It supplies a switch (`UISwitch`) which does roughly the same thing as a checkbox, but looks different. Is that what you want?

Comment: Oh no no it has to be like a checkbox... Can be?

Comment: In storyboard, click the button that opens the right panel (it's in the top right of the screen). You should be able to see the objects

Comment: Well, there is a library called objects but there is no checkboxes there...

Comment: Like Jonathan said, iOS has no checkboxes built in - but they aren't incredibly difficult to make

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to make a checkbox from a button (you need to connect the action to this method and also connect a property called `checkboxout`). Search SO for other examples, I just copied this from one of my programs. If this doesn't make sense then you should do some basic objective-c/xcode tutorials. (I hear Ray Wenderlich does good ones http://www.raywenderlich.com/)

Just so you know, Jonathan's answer is a better way to do things if you could possibly bring yourself to use a switch.

```
- (IBAction)checkbox:(id)sender 
    {
        UIButton *b = checkboxout;
        if (!boxChecked)
        {
            boxChecked = YES;
            [b setImage:isCheck forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            checkboxState = [NSNumber numberWithBool:boxChecked];
            return;
        }
        if (boxChecked)
        {
            boxChecked = NO;
            [b setImage:notCheck forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            checkboxState = [NSNumber numberWithBool:boxChecked];
            return;
        }
    }

//whatever your init method is for your view
{
    isCheck = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"];
    notCheck = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"];
    //probably other stuff
}
```

Comment: Here's another example of creating a checkbox button: https://gist.github.com/gerardp/1722387